# How can I get WNDCLASS to have a bitmap image as a background?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, gdi+

I filled out the WNDCLASS and the the hbrBackground property to my bitmap like

`wc.hbrBackground = CreatePatternBrush( LoadBitmap( hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE( "grey-texture.bmp" ) ) );`

This doesn't seem to change at all, the window is white like it is for defaults, so I need to find out what is going on here. Is CreatePatternBrush not the correct function to use for something like this? Couldn't it be done in such a way like this?

> hbrBackground = fromimagefile(string bitmap, bool tile);

Comment: Did you check the return value? check if it is NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Code should be checking for errors at each step. Following is just a raw sample.

```
HBITMAP hbmp = LoadBitmap(hInstance,MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP1));
if(NULL == hbmp)
{
    MessageBox(NULL,"BitMap Loading Failed.","Error",MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
}
else
{
    HBRUSH hbr = CreatePatternBrush(hbmp);
    if(NULL == hbr)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,"Brush Creation Failed.","Error",MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
    }
    else
    {
        wc.hbrBackground = hbr;
    }
}
```

Then, reply again with the result. I am not sure if your `LoadBitmap` function will work. Just like *BigBoss* told, we normaly use the resource.h to handle these things.
I suggest reading [Forger's Tutorials](http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/resources.html) if you want to learn this from beginning.

Answer (score 2):

See the following pages:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162462(v=vs.85).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183508(v=vs.85).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633576(v=vs.85).aspx

There are two types of brushes, logical and physical.  CreatePatternBrush creates a logical brush, but RegisterClass requires a physical brush.

Answer (score 1):

When you insert a resource in your RC file you can either name it with an string or with an int, but internally resources handle their resource using string. So when you name it with an int (actually an ID that defined in `resource.h` to an int), so when you have a resource that named with such an ID (integer ID), you must use `MAKEINTRESOURCE` to convert that ID to an `LPCTSTR` and pass it to function that load that resource but in your case you are passing an string `"grey-texture.bmp"` so you should not use `MAKEINTRESOURCE` and remember, `LoadBitmap` is designed to load resources from '.res` file that merged into your executive or DLL and can't load files on disk!!